# Fetch POST to send DELETE query to MySQL - is it safe?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, reactjs, web-hosting

Since many web hosting websites (such as infinityfree and 000webhost) block HTTP DELETE requests I found a way how to send DELETE query to MySQL by adding a password to HTTP POST body which triggers PHP to send DELETE query to MySQL.

But **is this safe since the password is visible in Front End** and so visible to any site visitor? Can someone do harm to my database by using this password like making SQL injection?

In React JS:

```
async function sendDeleteRequest(i) {
const bodyWithPassword = {
  ...props.updatedProducts[i],
  password: "kfI2KiIMOibKn0X98ufe$#!G^z78FNbbvI!fng0p*vk",
};
await fetch(Links["products"], {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(bodyWithPassword),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});
await props.refreshProductListContent();
```

}

In PHP:

```
//If HTTP body has password send DELETE query.
                if ($json["password"] = "kfI2KiIMOibKn0X98ufe$#!G^z78FNbbvI!fng0p*vk") {
                    $deleteProduct = new $json["productType"]($json);
                    $deleteProduct->deleteProduct($json);
                    return;
                }
                //If password isn't added in the body add product to database
                $newProduct = new $json["productType"]($json);
                $newProduct->addProduct($json, $newProduct);
```

Comment: Any DELETE query is definitely not safe at ALL lol.

Comment: Well it's true the password doesn't add any security because any user (or bot!) could take it and re-use it, and the password isn't unique per user. Whether you're vulnerable to SQL injection we don't know, because you didn't show us the code which runs the SQL. The solution to avoiding SQL injection is to use prepared statements and parameters. But that has absolutely nothing to do with whether you use HTTP DELETE or POST, or whether you use passwords or whatever else in your application.

Comment: SQL injection is a separate issue as well to, for instance, whether a user is _authorised_ to make such a deletion request. It's the job of your PHP code to look at the incoming request and decide whether the user is both authenticated and authorised to perform the request as per your business logic. I don't know whether you have any such authentication in your application, but you didn't mention it so I guess maybe not. What exactly are you trying to prevent with this idea? If it's just SQL injection then I mentioned the solution already. What other "harm" are you thinking of?

Comment: My delete query in PHP is made as follows:
public function deleteProduct($json)
    {
        $query = "DELETE FROM products 
        WHERE sku = ?";
        $sku = $json["sku"];
        $database = new Database();
        $database->deleteProduct($query, $sku);
        return;
    }
    public function deleteProduct($query, $sku)
    {
        $getConnection = new GetConnection;
        $conn = $getConnection->connect();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

        $stmt->execute([$sku]);

        //Close connection
        $this->conn = null;

        return;
    }

Comment: "Since many web hosting websites (such as infinityfree and 000webhost) block HTTP DELETE requests I found a way how to send DELETE query to MySQL by adding a password to HTTP POST" - this entire sentence makes ABSOLUTELY no sense. first of all, one can always use POST method to call a delete procedure. But either way, having password stored on the client just makes no sense, whatever method is used.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for *authentication*

Comment: Your code is already protected against SQL injection because you're using prepared statements and parameters. So you don't need to worry about that aspect. So it's a bit unclear what else exactly you are concerned about? As we said above, it sounds like maybe you need authentication and authorisation, but you need to clarify what threat you're worried about. P.S. In future please don't add code into comments where it's hard to read and out of context. Your question has an [edit] button, please use that to update your post.

Comment: Or maybe you could make do with something like CSRF tokens just to try and ensure the request does not come from a client which isn't your web application. It depends a lot on the context, which you haven't really explained. Did you also do any research into your scenario beforehand? Most things that people want to do in web applications have already been done before by someone else at some time.

Comment: @YourCommonSense How to call a delete procedure using POST method? Can you explain more in detail what you mean by "authentication"?

Comment: JUST a JSON {"action":"delete","id":666} sent to PHP using POST method.

Comment: @TedisRozenfelds a POST, GET, DELETE, PUT or any other HTTP request can run whatever code you want. You've already shown how to run a delete procedure using POST - your code is doing it now! What is supposed to be done in each of those HTTP methods (e.g. fetching data, adding data, updating data, deleting data) is purely by convention, nothing else. In reality anything is possible.

Comment: @ADyson Okey, so I am protected against SQL injection. But are there any other risks? It is a silly question, because I am new to coding and now I am thinking if there are other risks? Important fact: my password that I add to POST body is not used as password in any other place it is used only to call DELETE procedure in PHP!

Comment: Well why are you adding that password? What do you think could/would happen if there was no password? As I said above, are you worried about unauthorised users or applications calling the method? Or something else? The code you've shown doesn't appear to be vulnerable to anything else obvious.

Comment: authentication is basically just using a session. You don't need anything on a react part. Just start a session in PHP. There is A LOT of authentication tutorials in php

Comment: @ADyson so it is completely fine if I add to json one object like "action":"delete" or "password":"kfI2KiIMOibKn0X98ufe$#!G^z78FNbbvI!fng0p*vk" and it is perfectly okey?

Comment: It's fine, but adding the password doesn't do anything useful, for the reasons we explained right at the start. If you don't care about _who_ or _what_ sends the request then there's nothing obviously the matter with your code.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your answer! Now I understand that my question was silly. But your answers contributed to my growth greatly! Thank you all! So I will replace my Password object with action object.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is - **This is not safe**

Having a hard-coded password in ReactJS, which is a client-based Javascript code, means that it's accessible to anyone who visits and loads the Javascript file. Anyone can read it, use it and abuse it.

There is not enough code provided to see if there is a SQL injection vulnerability as such. You should review deleteProduct and addProduct functions and see if you have parameterized all the parameters passed to a SQL query.

In a scenario where your code was vulnerable to a SQL injection, anyone can grab the client-side encoded password and abuse the SQL injection vulnerability.

Regarding the request type, there is no actual difference between a **POST** and a **DELETE** request (technically speaking), apart from how your server side code processes it, which is what you write and decide. Obviously the development world has agreed to common sense on which each of the methods does here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods, which you should oblige by when doing development.